# New mortgage co reversing claim decision by old mortgage co

Tags: united-states, mortgage, insurance, home-insurance, alabama

I had a claim in March of last year due to hail/storm damage. The claim was paid by insurance to me and mortgage co. Then the mortgage co sent all the payments due, out to me in my name and the contractor's name. I signed them and gave them to contractor to endorse and keep. All of that was done last year.

I had to re-open the claim last week and insurance is going to pay for a new heat pump.  The mortgage co from last year is filing for bankruptcy. I have been transferred to a new loan service provider. They want to go back on the whole claim and are asking me to provide info that was sent to the old mortgage co and closed out with inspection.

I cannot provide this proof. Can they withhold my money for the heat pump? I am cancer survivor and cannot do without air.

Comment: @perennial-you misunderstand, they are not reversing anything, they can't.  The money was already pd by insurance co, then I sent it to old mortgage co last year, they sent it back to me in my name and contractor's name, I endorsed the check over and paid the contractor for the work which was completed, then old mortgage co did inspection on it and it was over at that point.  There is nothing to "reverse."  I am an insurance agent, is anyone versed in law governing mortgage companies in the state of Alabama?

Comment: you said `and they want to go back on whole claim` and that to me meant that are reversing something. So could you specify where  this heat pump comes into picture now and why you think the new company will withhold your money for that?

Comment: May be better to ask at https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: "I cannot provide this proof." - Can you ask them what they need the proof for? And what they expect the process to be, if you can or cannot provide it? It seems doubtful that they would want to withhold insurance money if it means that the collateral on the loan would be less valuable as a result of dong so.